# Make screen reader to read only the row that changed when all table is reloaded

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, aria-live

I have a table with multiple rows and columns. This table **as a whole** is reloaded by AJAX once in a while. When the table is reloaded, I want to inform screen reader users only about data that changed.

Going further, when there is a change in any cell, the screen reader should read the whole row to the user.

Furthermore - if a new row is added, it also should be read to the user as a whole.

What is the proper aria attributes that should be added and on which tags?

**Extra**: there also is a column, I don't want to be considered when looking for changes in the aria-live zone. But this cell should still be read if any other cell in the row changes.

Below is an example of code, I hoped to work, but instead of reading only changes, it reads the whole table after each reloads of the table.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Room</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
  <tr aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
    <td>Street 1</td>
    <td>Living room</td>
    <td>ON</td>
    <td aria-live="off">12:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
    <td>Street 1</td>
    <td>Bedroom</td>
    <td>OFF</td>
    <td aria-live="off">14:06</td>
  </tr>
  <tr aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
    <td>Street 2</td>
    <td>Living room</td>
    <td>ON</td>
    <td aria-live="off">19:59</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems to produce the desired behavior for me. Only the table row is being read aloud on update. I tested using NVDA and Firefox as well as Chrome browsers. What screen reader & browser combo are you testing with? See Fiddle here -- https://jsfiddle.net/0ytkbbfk/2/

Comment: @Josh If you are changing only the content of the cells - yes, it works perfectly. The problem is, that I am updating whole table at once (<table> tag is being rewritten). Usually the new table is same, but sometimes data in some cells is different. I am testing with both NVDA and JAWS.

Comment: That is a problem. If you're re-writing the entire table every time, then I don't think there's a good way to make it only read certain rows. This gets into the realm of sub-optimal, hack-ish solutions. Maybe after re-writing the table, you could then do a second update on the table row. That's all I can figure, unless you want to find a different way of updating that only changes the rows.

Comment: To make such table usable by screen reader users, I see only option to create a JS function, that will get table from AJAX request, compare it with table in HTML and update only fields, that are different. (tbh, I don't really like such way - that's why I looked for a solution here.)